# Convergence of a series concerning the multiplicative order of 2

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to bound the value of $v_p(2^n-1)$ and some of the series I obtain made me wonder about the following problem.

> Problem : 
>   When does the series $$\sum_{prime \: p} \frac{1}{(ord_p 2)^z} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\#\{p|ord_p2 = n\}}{n^z}$$ converge if $ord _p 2$ denotes the multiplicative order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for an odd prime $p$?

I noticed that it diverges when $z=1$ since $\#\{p|ord_p 2 = n\} \ge 1$ for all $n \ge 2$ except for $n=6$. Also, it converges when $z > 2$ because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\#\{p|ord_p2 = n\}}{n^z} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{ord_p2=n} \log p}{n^z} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log (2^n -1)}{n^z}$$ I'm especially interested about what happens when $z=2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\#\{p|ord_p 2 = n\} \ge 1$ doesn't hold for $n=6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that from $$\sum_{n|m}\#\{p|\operatorname{ord}_p2 = n\}=w(2^m-1)$$ we have
$$\zeta(z)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\#\{p|\operatorname{ord}_p2 = n\}}{n^z}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{w(2^n-1)}{n^z}=\int_1^\infty z\frac{\sum_{n\le x}w(2^n-1)}{x^{z+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
since $w(2^n-1)=O(n/\log n)$.
So the problem is equivalent to estimating the sum $$\sum_{n\le x}w(2^n-1)$$

Sadly, according to [this](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&q=mersenne%20number%20divisor%20sum%20estimate&ei=tJsZVPz2GIzs8AX984LgCA&url=https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~zeb/mersenne.pdf&cd=6&ved=0CDkQFjAF&usg=AFQjCNHh0SndlPjVNynui83ionQY0xrIEg&sig2=CEg4NHQWap-shfU1M6mbeg&cad=rjt) article, the current best bound is not enough to ensure the convergence of your sum, although it is conjectured to do so.

Cheers! :-)